# How can I ignore an argument?

Tags: function-construction, scripting

I made some code (attached below). It is meant to make a list of random numbers that is not divisible by some value k.

I wish to be able to not enter a value k, and have the code run regardless. It would simply make a list of random numbers with no regards for divisibility.

```
mylist[n_, r_, k_] := Module[{list, rain, appe},
  list = {};
  While[Length[list] < n, rain = RandomInteger[{r[[1]], r[[2]]}];
   appe = If[Mod[rain, k] == 0, , AppendTo[list, rain]]];
  list
 ]
```

Below are examples of inputs and outputs:

```
mylist[20, {1, 100}, 2]
Output: {69, 3, 47, 47, 69, 59, 95, 99, 61, 57, 69, 75, 63, 43, 93, 97, 87, 75, 65, 85}

mylist[20, {1, 50}]
Output:{32, 45, 33, 4, 19, 31, 45, 14, 29, 38, 4, 34, 8, 17, 5, 49, 24, 1, 43, 38}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using a default argument of `1`:

```
Clear[mylist]
SeedRandom[1];
mylist[n_, r_, k_ : 1] := Module[{list, rain, appe}, list = {};
  While[Length[list] < n, rain = RandomInteger[{r[[1]], r[[2]]}];
   appe = If[k > 1 && Mod[rain, k] == 0, , AppendTo[list, rain]]
   ];
  list]
```

*Usage:*

```
mylist[10, {1, 100}, 2]
```

> {81, 15, 1, 69, 75, 25, 5, 91, 71, 31}

```
mylist[10, {1, 100}]
```

> {49, 26, 45, 74, 70, 57, 48, 29, 69, 27}

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked.

Answer (score 10):

Probably the easiest and clearest way would be to just overload `mylist` with another definition:

```
mylist[n_, r_, k_] := <...what you already have...>;
mylist[n_, r_] := RandomInteger[r, n]
```

Answer (score 8):

While you didn't ask for advice, you could do this without the explicit While looping:

```
mylist[n_, r_, k_] := RandomChoice[Select[Range @@ r, Not[Divisible[#, k]] &], n]
```

Answer (score 7):

Use `Reap` and `Sow` instead of `AppendTo`.

Also you can do away with the `list` and `appe`. I've added a `test` argument, so you can pass in any test to accept numbers. And you can use `Divisible` instead of `Mod`:

```
mylist[n_, r_, test_] := Module[{rain, i = 0},
   Reap[While[i < n,
      rain = RandomInteger[r];
      If[test[rain], Sow[rain]; ++i]];
    ]][[2, 1]]
mylist[n_, r_] := mylist[n, r, Function[{x}, True]]
```

```
mylist[20, {1, 100}, Not[Divisible[#, 2]] &]
(* {33, 81, 57, 93, 83, 3, 21, 19, 57, 21, 97, 45, 11, 43, 21, 63, 97, 51, 7, 53} *)

mylist[20, {1, 100}]
(* {67, 78, 89, 23, 36, 72, 14, 97, 72, 64, 73, 100, 37, 70, 27, 5, 27, 85, 24, 67} *)
```

Comment: By passing in a `test` it gives you more flexibility to do things like this: `mylist[3, {1, 100}, x |-> Not@AnyTrue[{2, 3, 5}, Divisible[x, #] &]]` which will generate only numbers that are not divisible by 2,3, or 5.

Answer (score 5):

You can make the default value random:

```
mylist[n_, r_, k_ : RandomInteger[10]] := 
 Module[{list, rain, appe}, list = {};
  While[Length[list] < n, rain = RandomInteger[{r[[1]], r[[2]]}];
  appe = If[Mod[rain, k] == 0, , AppendTo[list, rain]]];
  list]
mylist[20, {1, 50}]
```

`{17, 1, 35, 45, 37, 31, 21, 19, 30, 27, 10, 17, 46, 45, 50, 22, 30, 21, 17, 38}`